# How to use what3words API in Salesforce to convert w3w address to coordinates

Tags: trigger, callout, rest, geolocation

I am using what3words (http://what3words.com) to save locations in Salesforce, by simply copying the w3w address from their app and pasting it into Salesforce using the mobile app.

I want to then convert the what3words address to lat/long using their API, which is in the form of a URL

```
http://api.what3words.com/w3w?key=YOURAPIKEY&string=word1.word2.word3
```

Is there a way to write code in Salesforce to do this automatically as my w3w address field gets populated?

I'm fairly experienced with Apex coding, but no experience with API's. I'm having a hard time searching for a good example/tutorial because every time I search for anything with "salesforce" and "api" in the search term, I only get the SF developer documentation results.

If anyone can point me in the direction of a good example/tutorial, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you need to look at is making a REST callout using...ready...Apex!

Yay...you already know it!

There are just a few things to note:

1. If you want this to happen upon save of this record, you will need to do it during a trigger.
2. If you are making a callout during a trigger, it must be annotated `@future(callout=true)`
3. You will need to be choosey as to whether to do this when you are doing bulk processing, as you only get a few callouts per transaction.
4. You will need to update the same record that was just saved...so make sure to prevent a recursive trigger execution (i.e. you save again, because you saved, because you saved before, etc...ad nauseum...ad fragor...) using a static variable.

There are a lot of articles on REST callouts from triggers including [this question here on SFSE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5602/http-callout-from-triggers). There is also this [video on REST callouts](https://youtu.be/705SeyjpoFs) (to StackExchange, ironically) by Matt Kaufman from Dreamforce last year.