# Bulk Address verification

Tags: trigger, data-loader

I have custom button "Verify Address" which calls trigger and Webservice API for address verification. 
Now my requirement is , when records are uploaded through data loader how can i call this trigger which have webservice api calls.

Comment: Would it be enough to kick off a batch job?  Does the person using the batch loader have access to the SalesForce?  And would they be able to run a job?

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke @future method from your trigger that will do address validation for you.

[HTTP Callout from Triggers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5602/http-callout-from-triggers)