# i need trigger a sobject(opportunity) of custom field(on hand quantity)

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, controller, administration

i need trigger a value before saving the record into database( i have a custom field product name in opportunity when ever i enter product name it should call callouts(oracle ebs-cloud) for number of quantity available for that product it should be place into quantity field (opportunity) before saving record this my requirement....

we can use trigger before saving record

Comment: what's your question? where exactly you are facing issues?

Comment: Tharun, the only issue I see as of now could be comparing the product name with 'null' string, whereas it should be **opp.Product_name__c != null**, null without quotes.

Comment: i need trigger a value before saving the record into database( i have a custom field product name  in opportunity when ever i enter product name it should call callouts(oracle ebs-cloud) for number of quantity available for that product it should be place into quantity field (opportunity) before saving record this my requirement--Santanu Boral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the clarification in comments:

It can not be done in realtime as you are expecting, because you will be making a callout and callout will be done from a helper class's **@future** method, and future methods are asynchronous. Their results are not sure to be in real time.

So, what you can do, you can call a @future method, and pass the Opportunity Id. Once the response comes back, Opportunity will be updated in future method then.

You can also refer the below link for more details.

[Click here for more information](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5602/http-callout-from-triggers)

Comment: as u mention i am using @future .my question is value should come into quantity before we go  for save

Comment: That is what I explained, @future method is asynchronous, it's results are not real time. One workaround would be to use the visualforce page, and making the callout from visualforce page controller, and rerendering only the field of amount with the response. No trigger will be involved in it.

Comment: thanks bro we can call  callouts for standard sobject  in vf pages

Comment: and value from callout should set in custom field when it calls

Comment: Thats correct. You can use rerender attribute to do the same. Please upvote and mark the answer if it helped you.

Comment: can  u please provide some sample exmaple

Comment: povide me sample exmaple for standard sboject @NITISH SINGHAL